# Iterating through Object nested within another Object with HtmlService in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, object, google-apps-script

Please Help,

I have created an object in a googleScript file which I have then have passed via a withSuccessHandler to an HTML file where I am then trying to iterate through the values in an object nested within the main object.  We'll call it object_A, and it is defined below.

```
    object_A = {
    id=[axObsNum, axObAspect, axObElevation, axObLocation, axObCoordinates, axObDate, axObTrigger, axObType, axObSize, axObSlopeAngle, axObNotes], 
    parsed=[{3=[,,,,,2014-08-06,,,,,],2=[,,,,,2014-08-06,,,,,],1=[,,,,,2014-08-06,,,,,]}], 
    ob=[{"1":"","2":"","3":""}, {"1":"","2":"","3":""}, {"1":"","2":"","3":"","4":"","5":""}, {"1":"","2":"","3":""}, {"1":"","2":"","3":""}, {"1":"2014-08-06","2":"2014-08-06","3":"2014-08-06"}, {"1":"","2":"","3":""}, {"1":"","2":"","3":""}, {"1":"","2":"","3":""}, {"1":"","2":"","3":""}, {"1":"","2":"","3":""}], 
    key=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    header=[Ax Obs Num, Ax Ob Aspect, Ax Ob Elevation, Ax Ob Location, Ax Ob Coordinates, Ax Ob Date, Ax Ob Trigger, Ax Ob Type, Ax Ob Size, Ax Ob Slope Angle, Ax Ob Notes]
}
```

Specifically I want the parsed values of object_A.  In the googleScript file I can easily get these be declaring object_A.parsed[0][2].  I know parsed is an array, so [0] gives me the first, and only, value in that array and then with the [2] i get the values for that key-value.

My question is, why doesn't this work in the html file where I've declared a simple function to handle the return from the the withSuccessHandler function.  That simple code is as follows, and the result will be undefined.

```
function withSuccess(obj){
console.log(obj.parsed[0][2])
}
```

Why? Please Help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change all your `=`'s to `:`s. That should fix your problem.

Object members are defined like this: `{ foo: "bar", bar: "baz" }`. Equal signs are used for single assignment statements.

This would be likely more correct as per your above object (added line breaks for clarity):

```
object_A = {
    id: [
        axObsNum,
        axObAspect,
        axObElevation,
        axObLocation,
        axObCoordinates,
        axObDate,
        axObTrigger,
        axObType,
        axObSize,
        axObSlopeAngle,
        axObNotes,
    ], 
    parsed: [{
        3: [,,,,,2014-08-06,,,,,],
        2: [,,,,,2014-08-06,,,,,],
        1: [,,,,,2014-08-06,,,,,],
    }], 
    ob: [
        {"1": "", "2": "", "3": ""},
        {"1": "", "2": "", "3": ""},
        {"1": "", "2": "", "3": "", "4": "", "5": ""},
        {"1": "", "2": "", "3": ""},
        {"1": "", "2": "", "3": ""},
        {"1": "2014-08-06", "2": "2014-08-06", "3": "2014-08-06"},
        {"1": "", "2": "", "3": ""},
        {"1": "", "2": "", "3": ""},
        {"1": "", "2": "", "3": ""},
        {"1": "", "2": "", "3": ""},
        {"1": "", "2": "", "3": ""},
    ],
    key: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    header: [
        "Ax Obs Num",
        "Ax Ob Aspect",
        "Ax Ob Elevation",
        "Ax Ob Location",
        "Ax Ob Coordinates",
        "Ax Ob Date",
        "Ax Ob Trigger",
        "Ax Ob Type",
        "Ax Ob Size",
        "Ax Ob Slope Angle",
        "Ax Ob Notes",
    ],
}
```

Note that your header property may also be spewing SyntaxErrors, so I gave a suggested fix above (assuming they are strings as they appear they should be).